# Call REST API using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, rest

I am new to Node.JS, I want to request and get back the response by calling a REST API from Node.JS. I have checked in SOAP UI and I am getting the response in JSON. But I am getting the error when I am trying to run the .js file.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49MSR.jpg)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIqPq.png)

Updated Output:
[Getting ENOTFOUND Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjX31.png)

Comment: You should paste code and it's output instead of pasting the screenshot. Welcome to the Stack overflow community.

Comment: Welcome, instead of posting an image with the code (that is barely readable), please just append your code to the question. You're having different formats inside the textbox which you can choose of.

Comment: I will do from the next time

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjX31.png Getting this error. Could you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma on line 9, before "headers".

Comment: Add the specific part of the code example to make this answer more understandable for future users which will have the same issues.

Comment: The code is literally an image. I am not copying it.

Comment: I've just seen it. So, let's wait till its posted above.

Comment: @RichardE.  I have updated the output after giving comma. Please check the error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma at line 8, right after `method: 'GET'`.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: SO tells me I have to gain a reputation of 50 before posting comments.

Comment: @FredoCorleone I have updated the output after giving comma. Please check the error. Thanks

Comment: @Dataoverflow Try removing ```https://``` in front of your host address at line 5.

Answer (score 1):

comma is missing after method : 'GET'

Comment: I have updated the output after giving comma. Please check the error. Thanks